# Prove that (1)(3)...(2n+1) / (2)(4)...(2n) is unbounded and increasing.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

I got this problem off of an intro analysis book, and I'm stuck on the unbounded portion.

We know that the equation $a_n$ is always increasing when there is some k that represents the product:

$k = (\frac{1}{2}) (\frac{3}{4}) ... (\frac{2n - 1}{2n})$

This means $a_n$ is $k(2n+1)$ and $a_{n+1}$ is $k(2n + 1)(\frac{2n+3}{2n+2})$, which we can simplify to prove that $a_{n+1} \geq a_n$.

I'm stuck on the next part, however. How do I simplify the equation in a way that will yield an unbounded sequence that is always less than $a_n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint. The first part is correct. For the second part let
$$a_n=\frac{3\cdot 5\cdots (2n+1)}{2\cdot 4\cdots (2n)}=\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{2k+1}{2k}=\prod_{k=1}^n\left(1+\frac{1}{2k}\right)$$
then 
$$\ln(a_n)=\sum_{k=1}^n\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{2k}\right)\geq \frac{\ln(2)}{2}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}$$
because  $\ln(1+x)$ is concave and $\ln(1+x)\geq \ln(2)x$ for $0<x\leq 1$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: So I know that the sum $\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\frac{1}{k}}$ is unbounded, which makes the original sequence unbounded, and I get why ln(x+1) is greater than ln(2)x. But is there another way of doing this? I feel like I would have never derived this kind of proof myself...

Comment: @AbhiV Yes, that is correct. You can also say that $\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{2k}\right)$ is asymptotically equivalent to $\frac{1}{2k}$ (their ratio has limit $1$) and therefore the corresponding series  have the same behaviour.